# Hola tengo un problema, estoy viendo spring security y estoy en la configuration para habilitar rutas

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, spring-security

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno el problema es que cuando le paso el cursor me dice que las funciones estan depreciadas pero me parece raro porque en cuando escribo el codigo en sugerencias me sale que .authorizeHttpRequests() y formLogin() no estan depreciadas excepto and() que me sale que si esta depreciado, estoy usando la version de spring security 6.1.4

Answer (score 1):

La razón de encadenar los métodos "and" en versiones anteriores era por que queríamos obtener HttpSecurity devuelta, pero en Spring Security 6 ya no se utilizan debido a que los métodos ya lo devuelven.

Tu código debería verse así:

```
httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
    auth.requestMatchers("/v1/index2").permitAll();
    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
})

.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())

.build();
```

El método "authorizeHttpRequests()" solía devolver AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry lo que hacía que en la cadena de métodos debieras llamar a "and()" para recibir el objeto HttpSecurity nuevamente.

Ahora el método devuelve directamente HttpSecurity y al objeto AuthorizationManagerR... te lo sirven en una interfaz similar a `Consumer<T>` donde con una expresión lambda puedes acceder a él en su propio "scope" y utilizarlo desde ahí.

En la versión 5.2 agregaron [Spring Security Lambda DSL](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/21/spring-security-lambda-dsl) donde anunciaban que la forma antigua aún sería valida, pero en la en la versión 6 la documentación anuncia que [dejará de ser compatible](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests()) la forma antigua en la futura versión 7.